# Set of vectors tangent to $f^{-1}(p) \in \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ need not be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm asked to show by example that...

> The set of vectors tangent at a point $p$ of a level set need not in general be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$.

My method is:

Consider the set of vectors such that $y = x^2$. This is not a vector space of $R^2$: $$(x_1, x_1^2) + (x_2, x_2^2) = (x_1 + x_2, x_1^2 + x_2)\\\text{and} \\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 \neq (x_1 + x_2)^2$$

In order for this to be the set of vectors tangent to some point $p$ of a level set, these vectors must be the derivative of some parametrized curves whose images are contained in the level set, $f^{-1}(c \in \mathbb{R})$. Thus, the curves must be of the form:

$$\alpha(t) = (\frac{1}{2}t^2 + c_1, \frac{1}{3}t^3 + c_2) ~~\text{where}~~ c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$

Since $\alpha(t) \subseteq f^{-1}(c)$, we construct an $f(p \in \mathbb{R^2})$ such that $f^{-1}(c) = \alpha(t)$ at some $c$. Thus, we want a function such that some combination of $x = \frac{1}{2}t^2 + c_1$ and $y = \frac{1}{3}t^3 + c_2$ is a constant. After some toying around, I came up with letting $c_1 = c_2 = 0$: $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^3}{y^2} \\ c = \frac{9}{8}$$

That is, we can work backwards: When we consider the level curve $f^{-1}(\frac{9}{8})$, we can satisfy $f(x,y) = \frac{9}{8}$ with the curve $x = \frac{1}{2}t^2$ and $y = \frac{1}{3}t^3$, whose derivative is the set of vectors such that $y = x^2$, which is not a vector space.

Is... this ok? I hardly have any intuition regarding this, and there's a feeling of uncertainty associated with this solution. Did I miss anything? Am I mixing things up? Furthermore, is there some simpler example that is going over my head?

Comment: Regarding a simpler example: consider the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.  The level curves of this function would then be $c=x^2+y^2$ for some constant $c$ -- that is, they would be circles of arbitrary radius centered about the origin.  Any tangent space to a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at the origin does not itself pass through the origin, and hence is not a vector subspace.  This is just from reading the highlighted question at the top; if I've misinterpreted your question, please let me know.

Comment: The tangent space is always considered to consist of vectors based at the origin. The tangent *plane* studied in typical multivariable calculus classes typically is based at the point in question.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x) = x_2^2-x_1^2$ and consider $L = f^{-1}(\{0\})$. It is straightforward to show that $L = \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,1)^T \} \cup \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,-1)^T \} $ and it is clear that this is not a vector subspace.